# define the font path

Tags: php, imagemagick

how can I define and use local fonts on the server?

```
exec(Init::$static['path_imagemagick'].'convert -background none -fill "#04202e" -size x20 label:"test" gfx/gen/tmp.png');
```

I have some fonts in this path:

./fonts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation on the [`-font`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=a8jgr7qn2751p067tcej64hk04#font) parameter (emphasis mine):

> `-font name`
>
> set the font to use when annotating
>   images with text, or creating labels. 
>   To print a complete list of fonts, use
>   the -list font option (for versions
>   prior to 6.3.6, use 'type' instead of
>   'font').
>
> **In addition to the fonts specified by
>   the above pre-defined list, you can
>   also specify a font from a specific
>   source.** For example Arial.ttf is a
>   TrueType font file, ps:helvetica is
>   PostScript font, and x:fixed is X11
>   font.